# Keyboard cursor problem

Tags: keyboard

I have a strange problem. While I'm typing, in any program, i get a BEEP from my computer and the keyboard cursor goes away. So I have to point back where I'm typing and start to write again.

Comment: Can you give more details? Operating system? Computer type (laptop? desktop?) Details about keyboard and mouse?

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe one of your keys is not releasing properly (blocked or so) the beep that your hear is very likely the one for the keyboard buffer full, what also explains that your cursor "runs away". Try to find out which key is hanging, if you see nothing it is some whitespace key (Tab, space, arrows, ...)

The only other explanation for beeps related to keyboard is when you engage different incompatible keys from the keyboard matrix point of view creating a conflict. That means the system cannot identify which key you typed. But this does not apply here I think.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a laptop/netbook? If so, you may be inadvertently bumping the touch pad and moving  your cursor out of the text box.